# Emulate Android Wear on Android tablet

Tags: tablet, android-wear

I have Dell Venue 3830 un-rooted, Android 4.4.2. I want a kind of Android Wear emulator so I can run Android Wear apps.

What should I do so I can run Wear apps or make my Android tablet an Android Wear?

Comment: What Wear apps could you possibly want to run that don't have (better) tablet counterparts?

Comment: I want to run android wear apps(try them).

Comment: Emulating Android within Android on a low-end device isn't going to work.  You're also not likely to find a Wear ROM for a 8" tablet.

Comment: Josh Holland's answer would be the only answer, editing your question doesn't change what the answer is. Its either you use the emulator on PC or port it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the Wear emulator on a Windows PC according to http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-2452471/install-android-wear-emulator.html, although running Wear on a tablet is probably virtually impossible (unless you feel like [porting it](http://www.xda-developers.com/want-to-play-with-android-wear-without-setting-up-the-emulator-heres-a-system-dump/)...).

(Copy/pasted instructions for posterity)

---

1. Log on to your Windows PC.
2. Download Android SDK by going to [this link](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).
3. Once downloaded, extract the Android SDK.zip file.
4. From the extracted folder, double-click the SDK Manager application.
5. Go to Packages.
6. On the Packages window, check the Android SDK Tools checkbox under the Tools section. (If the version of the SDK Tools is below the 22.6.)
7. Under the Android 4.4.2 section, check the ARM EABI v7a System Image checkbox to install the Android wear.
8. Under the Extras section, check the Android Support Library checkbox if the update is available.
9. When the things are in place, click Install.
10. From the Choose Packages to Install window, click to select the Accept License radio button and click Install to start installation.
11. Once the installation is done, go to the C:\Android SDK folder.
12. Once there, double-click the eclipse.exe file from the eclipse folder to launch the application.
13. On the opened window, click the Window tab from the top.
14. From the expanded list, click Android Virtual Device Manager.
15. Once the Android Virtual Device Manager box opens up, click New from the right pane to create a new Android Virtual Device.
16. On the next window, populate the available fields with the most suitable values and click OK. **(See footnote)**
17. From the opened window, click the Start button available in the right.
18. When the Launch Options box appears, click Launch.
19. Wait till the Android Emulator is loaded.
20. Turn on Bluetooth on your PC (in case of laptop).
    Note: You may have to get a USB Bluetooth device and connect it to your computer if you are using a desktop PC.
21. Once the process is complete, on the smartphone, launch the Android Wear app.
    Note: Make sure that the Android Wear app is already downloaded, installed and functioning on your Android smartphone.
22. On your smartphone again, tap the More icon (icon with the three vertical dots) from the top-right corner.
23. Tap Pair with a new wearable from the available list.
    Note: If prompted, turn on the Bluetooth on your smartphone.
24. On the Choose a device interface, tap the Settings icon (icon with the Gear symbol) located at the top-right corner.
25. Finally, tap Pair with emulator from the next screen to pair the smartphone with the emulator.
26. After the devices are paired, you can test the apps and use the Android Wear Emulator as per your requirements.

**Footnote:** Choose the following options to populate available fields:

1. Provide the name of the Android Virtual Device in the AVD Name field.
2. Select the desired device from the Device drop-down. (i.e. Round or Square)
3. From the Target list, choose Android 4.4.2-API Level 19 (or greater).
4. Select Android Wear ARM (armeabi-v7a) from the CPU/ABI drop-down list.
5. Check the Hardware keyboard present checkbox.
6. From the Skin drop-down list, choose either AndroidWearSquare or AndroidWearRound as desired.
7. Keep the values in the other fields as default.

Comment: Well at least it can be emulated! ;) +1